# Is there a way to redirect the user to okta for login without using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, okta

I have a java application running on wildfly server, that uses ejbs and Servlet HttpSecurity. There is no Spring Boot implemented. I am working on a task where access control of the application must be handled by Okta. Basically when user hits the url to access the application, they must be redirected to Okta log in page, where they provide the credentials. And after authentication, user can access the app.

Is there any way this task can be done without using Spring Boot?

I tried https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java#usage-guide but it requires username and password to be provided in the code itself which is not the requirement.

Comment: You can simply achieve this by using web filter, it is nothing to do with Spring Boot.

Comment: @LHCHIN Thank you for the reply. But I have to handle the application's each request & response using OKTA(authentication and authorization) too. And almost all of the examples I found online has Spring Boot implemented.

Comment: Have you visited this page [link](https://developer.okta.com/code/java/). (I just googled "OKTA Java example" and it was the first result.)